# How to create snapshot with libvirt API in python

Tags: python, virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I want to manage (create, delete, list...) snapshots in KVM with the libvirt API. After some googling I found the libvirt-domain-snapshot in the link below but I did not find this module for python.

https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain-snapshot.html

How can I access the libvirt-domain-snapshot module from python or is there another way to manage snapshots through the libvirt API?

Answer (score 6):

Use `pip install libvirt-python` to install libvirt bindings. Then `libvirt_connection = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')` to create connection to libvirt. Get the vm `vm_dom = libvirt_connection.lookupByUUIDString(domain_uuid)` (`domain_uuid` is a string that contains UUID of your domain). And finally call

```
vm_dom.snapshotCreateXML(
                SNAPSHOT_XML_TEMPLATE.format(snapshot_name=snapshot_name),
                libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_SNAPSHOT_CREATE_ATOMIC
)
```

where `SNAPSHOT_XML_TEMPLATE` looks like this:

```
SNAPSHOT_XML_TEMPLATE = """<domainsnapshot>
  <name>{snapshot_name}</name>
</domainsnapshot>"""
```

This will create disc and ram snapshot with given name. libvirt-python compatible with python3 and python2.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you would look at [libvirt's docs](https://libvirt.org/docs.html) and look under `Application Development` -> `Language bindings`, you'll see their API has [Python Bindings](https://libvirt.org/python.html).

Since they import a `libvirt` module that isn't packed with a regular install of Python there's a big chance you will have to install it yourself. Luckily though it appears to be [part of the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libvirt-python).

So you could probably just run:

`python -m pip install libvirt` or `python3 -m pip install libvirt` (or any other equivalent, depending on which version of Python you are using) to install the module.

Then you're all set :).